# How to allocate number of bytes memory using new in C++

Tags: c++, c, malloc, new-operator

I want to replace malloc call in my program and allocate number of bytes of memory.

```
Zone *zone = (Zone *)malloc(allocSize <= JSON_ZONE_SIZE ? JSON_ZONE_SIZE : allocSize);
```

How to write c++ code using new keyword for above code snippet. My hardware not supporting malloc function call.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, what's your problem? Be specific! Tell us what you tried, what worked and what didn't work. BTW: Get a good book on C++. You can't just patch up things like above and expect to produce good, maintainable and reliable C++ programs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace 'malloc' and 'free' with 'new' and 'delete'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675416/how-to-replace-malloc-and-free-with-new-and-delete)

Comment: out of curiosity: why do you wan to do that? What is the advantage? Imho you should rather get rid of manual memory management alltogether

Comment: You're not allocating the right amount of memory for your struct - I'd guess that "JSON_ZONE_SIZE" means you're writing a string to the rest and hiding the fact that there's a character array after your struct.  Don't do that (it's bad practice, even in C!).  Put a string in your struct.

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong with just new'ing the struct?

```
struct Zone {
    Zone *next;
    size_t used;
} *head;

Zone *zone = new Zone();
```

Comment: Actually, I want to edit existed code and need to assign number of bytes.

Comment: `memAllocSize = (allocSize <= JSON_ZONE_SIZE) ? JSON_ZONE_SIZE : allocSize;
 Zone* zone = static_cast<Zone*>(::operator new(memAllocSize));`

I hope I solved my problem. I achieved like this